# Counter in AS3 "without dynamic text field"

Tags: c++, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

What is the best way to program an LED number tick. I need to have a number display that goes up to 1,000,000.00. Dynamic text fields are not an option because of symbol instances. How would I make a counter?

## ANIMATION

The numbers move in increments like an LED display. This

## NUMBERS

The numbers multiple by ten each space over
decimal point numbers are not whole, so they go really fast
There's a 16,000 frame limit in flash

## SYMBOLS

column of numbers that moves in increments, for each number place

## WHAT WOULD IT REQUIRE?

numbers move at a rate in multiples of 10
decimal points times one hundred

## FRAME BASED OR TIME BASED?

There's a 16,000 frame limit in Flash
Time based method would require a lot of code
the add and remove child issue
[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/number_example.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/number_example.jpg)

## TRANSITION EFFECT

A "tick"
move 10 pixels each time etc.
9 and 0 roll over smoothly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flash, and to achieve the result in your picture there, I would create 2 MovieClips:

- A black bar with a decimal point
- The grey digits in a column, 0 -> 0, as suggested by your pic

Then, combine the black bar and 9 of the digit columns into a single MovieClip to represent your counter, along with a custom base class for it. This allows you fine-grained control over the entire counter.

Provide a `CounterClip::Step()` or `::Tick()` method (or whatever you want to call it) that can move the individual columns. You can use the `flash.transitions.Tween` class to create smooth animations (I think thats what it's called... I'm a bit rusty.)

If you find you need more than the 9 columns, you can change your Counter MovieClip class to support dynamically adding more digits.

Answer (score 0):

i think it totally depends on the transition effect you are using while switching the numbers.